# Django зависимые поля на форме

Tags: django

Допустим у меня имеются следующие модели:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

Задача: Есть форма с двумя полями, первая отображает список объектов A, вторая список объектов B. Необходимо чтобы поле со списком объектов B фильтровалось соответственно выбранному объекту A.

Сейчас это реализовано в виде ajax функции на сервере которая принимает выбранный объект A, и возвращает список принадлежащий объектов B + и соответственно на клиенте код js который отправляет выбранный объект и подменяет список отфильтрованными.

Бывают случаи когда на форме вложенных моделей не две, а три, четыры.. в итоге получается много "тупой" логики.
Возможно ли это сделать средствами django или его дополнениями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects), [django-chained-selects](https://github.com/RaD/django-chained-selects)

Comment: django-chained-selects то что нужно, позволяет всё сделать на уровне форм, спс!